# using jquery to create a text input combination?

Tags: jquery, textfield

i was wondering whether it was possible for jquery to make a text field only accept a combination of 3 letters and 4 numbers (eg ABC1234) - in that order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MEvj3/

Here's a simplified example of one way.

```
<input type="text" class="code" />
```

```
$("input.code").keyup(function(){
    this.value = this.value.match(/[A-Z]{3}([0-9]{1,4})?|[A-Z]{1,3}/i)[0];
});
```

Comment: That fiddle isn't working for me Joseph. All characters are deleted as soon as you type.

Comment: I don't really know much about regex, could you also change the example to allow for lowercase a-z too please :)

Comment: @SoulieBaby certainly.  you can just add `i` to the end of the regex (after the last `/`) to make it case insensitive.  edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#text-input").focusout(function(){
    var regex = "[\w]{3}[\d]{4}"
    if(this.value.match(regex)){
        // display success
    }else{
        /// display error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created an input with a maxlength...

```
<input id="testy" type="text" maxlength="7" />
```

...then you could just check it's length and jQuery's `e.which`:

```
$('#testy').keydown(function (e) {
    var keycode = e.which,
        isLetter = keycode > 64 && keycode < 90,
        isNumber = keycode > 47 && keycode < 58,
        l = this.value.length;
    if (keycode !== 8 && ((l < 4 && !isLetter) || (l > 3 && !isNumber))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note that there are some gotchas:

- I don't know how portable this is to different OSs (maybe not such a big deal when using jQuery)
- I don't have a numpad, and maybe those keycodes are different (maybe not such a big deal when using jQuery)
- The <kbd>Del</kbd> button will be disabled

Honestly, the code is pretty sloppy. It's just supposed to get the basic idea across; you'll probably have to tweak it to get something that really works for your project.